# More effective jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I  have nine different toggles and panels that work just the way I want to. However, I suspect that my jQuery code could be a lot shorter?

Sorry for the newbie question, I'm still learning.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle1").click(function(){
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle2").click(function(){
        $("#panel2").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle3").click(function(){
        $("#panel3").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle4").click(function(){
        $("#panel4").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle5").click(function(){
        $("#panel5").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle6").click(function(){
        $("#panel6").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle7").click(function(){
        $("#panel7").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle8").click(function(){
        $("#panel8").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#toggle9").click(function(){
        $("#panel9").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT: Here's the basic HTML structure as well. I should have included that in the first place. I only included the first three toggles as I'm not allowed to post to much code here. All nine divs look exactly the same.

```
<div class="col">
    <h2 id="toggle1"></h2>
    <ul id="panel1">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <h2 id="toggle2"></h2>
    <ul id="panel2">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <h2 id="toggle3"></h2>
    <ul id="panel3">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You could probably reduce all the click handlers to three lines using DOM traversal, but it depends how your HTML is structure. Could you please edit the question to include a sample of the relevant HTML

Comment: Create a class example "toggleClass" and include it in every toggle.

Do a for each loop in jquery for .toggleClass which does the function once.

Comment: @FarhanQasim with sensible markup this can be done with zero loops (in our code).

Comment: @DOMcat Please edit your HTML in to the question so we can stop all these downvotes on the answerers making terrible assumptions and providing some really hacky solutions.

Comment: as the above comment states^, please provide html. Downvoting is too much in this question.

Comment: Included the HTML, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There should be an achievement for this question: 'Started a downvote war'. Silver at least.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan A special hat maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your code you can use the [jQuery starts with attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) (`[attribute^='value']`) and [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$("[id^='toggle']").click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^='toggle']").click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle("fast");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <h2 id="toggle1">1</h2>
  <ul id="panel1">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <h2 id="toggle2">2</h2>
  <ul id="panel2">
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <h2 id="toggle3">3</h2>
  <ul id="panel3">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: For future reference, be wary of using `.next(selector)` as it doesn't find the *next* element that matches the selector, it only gives the next element and then only if it matches.

Answer (score -1):

This will work to select all the id's that contains toggle:

```
$("[id^=toggle]").click(function(){
    $(this).next("[id^=panel]").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

You can find more info about selector in jQuery page: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^="toggle"]').click(function(e){
        $('#panel'+idIndex($(this))).slideToggle("fast");
    });
});

function idIndex(e){
  return parseInt(e.attr('id').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''));
}
```

---

With [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^="toggle"]').click(function(e){
        $(this).next('[id^="panel"]').slideToggle("fast");
        //you can even use 'ul' instead of '[id^="panel"]'
    });
});
```

With [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.col').each(function(){
        var col = this;
        $(col).find('h2').click(function(){
          //the same as the previous, you can use '[id^="toggle"]' instead of h2
          $(col).find('ul').slideToggle('fast');
          //and here, '[id^="panel"]'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

How about something like this?

```
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    $("#toggle" + i.toString()).click(function(){
        $("#panel" + i.toString()).slideToggle("fast");
    });
}
```

Comment: Broken code (one extra `"`) and clumsy double `i=0` and `i+=1`, but meh, this one doesn't get as silently downvoted as the other answers.

Comment: eh `i++` is just too subjective. Also the extra `"` was a typo but if the person "using" this code doesn't know how to diagnose that and fix it they probably shouldn't be using other peoples solutions.

Comment: Yeah I know that, it's just that other (really) working answers got massively downvoted for some reason, and yours didn't. And `i++` is just more elegant than `i+=1`, you can't argue with that :)

Answer (score -2):

Just use a 1-9 loop... That's a one-liner in ES6

```js
for(let i=1; i<10; i++) $(`#toggle${i}`).click(() => $(`#panel${i}`).slideToggle("fast") )
```

Comment: You will not obtain an explanation, since there are so many smart people here that writes perfect code and helps better than nobody can help.

Comment: That's what I thought. Because this one-liner works, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I agree it works, but there are a *lot* of better ways of doing it, one of which could be provided if the OP took the time to add their HTML to the question. For the record, I haven't downvoted you.

Comment: In absence of HTML layout, I have just rewritten OP's original code. It's not the best way of doing it, of course ( I would never attach one event listener per id) but at least it answers the question and it works, so I'm not sure I deserved being taken down by cow-boys (not you, noted), but meh

Comment: Nice answer. If you could explain the various ES6 nuances I think it would help a lot of folks.

Comment: Okay (and thanks!), but I'm not sure what to explain. What don't you understand, for instance?